# Log in with Google plus in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, google-plus

I am getting this error when trying to login in my website on localhost:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Google_ServiceResource' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\picivity\third_party\google-api-php-client\src\contrib\Google_PlusService.php on line 25

Fatal error: Class 'Google_Client' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\picivity\application\front\libraries\Googleplus.php on line 16
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are missing classes. make sure you have include them.

Comment: @jenn plz answer the question if DalmTo comment is useful

Comment: There was path problem. @YajliMaclo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google API wont work on your localhost but it will work on live server. I once had this issue

Comment: @Nevermore if you run same code on live server it will work, but it will show error on your localhost

Comment: @NavedMunshi True. It worked. Thanks for the quick reply man. Appreciate it.